# integrating sorting through angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

trying to get sorting figured out for this json data i'm getting from jsonplaceholder.com This is what the data I'm trying to sort by looks like:
 (http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums)(http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos).  I'm trying to get it to sort by userId and amount of pictures from the photos api per album. I've tried filtering but I would like a sort button that would arrange all the albums asynchronously in angular if theres a way here's my html:

```
<div ng-repeat="album in albumData|filter:q" id="thumbWrapper">
                <h3>Album By: {{album.userId}}</h1> 
                <h4>Title: </h4><button class="show" ng-click="showme = !showme">{{album.title}}</button>
                <div id="thumbList" ng-show="showme"class="albumContent">
                    <ul ng-controller="PhotoCtrl" id="thumbList">
                        <li ng-repeat="photo in photoData">
                            <div ng-if="album.id == photo.albumId">
                                <img ng-click="photo.zoomed = !photo.zoomed" ng-src="{{ photo.zoomed ? photo.url : photo.thumbnailUrl}}">
                                <p ng-click="delete($index)">x</p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and my js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('AlbumCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums").then(function(response) {
        $scope.albumData = response.data;
        //console.log($scope.albumData);
    });
});
app.controller('PhotoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos").then(function(response) {
        $scope.photoData = response.data;

    });

    $scope.delete = function(index) {
    var del = "/" + (index + 1);
        $http.delete("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos" + del).then(function(response) {
            $scope.photoData.splice(index, 1);
           // console.log($scope.albumData);
        });
    };
});
```

any tips would be awesome

Comment: are you trying to group and sort

Comment: yes exactly i'm trying to get it to group and sort

Comment: and showing that grouped array isnt it